# How to fix Call to undefined method Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register()

Tags: wordpress, elementor

My website suddenly started giving `Call to undefined method Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register()` I haven't done any upgrade of the elementor for it to break. Currently it is running v3.3.0.

How do I fix this ?